# Spring repository query to return a map with day as key

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

Having an entity that contains a column named "workDay" how can I make query to get all entries in a map where key is "workDay" and value a list of entities. 
Any hing is welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You want a query method to return `Map<Date, List<?>>`. [`Map` is not a supported return type for query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_return_types). Therefore, you cannot use the default implementation to achieve what you are looking for.

You can create a [custom repository implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) that queries the database and returns the desired `Map<Date, List<?>>`.

Comment: It would be really great, if you could provide a simple example.